# "cursor_location property cannot be animated" error in Blender

Tags: animation, properties

I'm trying to make an animation but every time I press <kbd>I</kbd> to get the frame, now it says "cursor_location property cannot be animated".

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason that you would not use an Empty object instead of the 3D Cursor?

Answer (score 3):

Where in Blender UI is your mouse cursor hovering when you press the <kbd>I</kbd> key?
Are you by any chance hovering the *3D Cursor Position* coordinate boxes?

You seem to be trying to animate the 3D cursor position, which apparently is not animatable. As far as I know it is part of Blender UI data or temporary run time data, I think, not a property from your scene, and thus not a type or data that can be stored or animated.

Answer (score 3):

This is not an error to be fixed - data associated with the interface intentionally doesn't support animation.

I'm not sure why you would want to animate the cursor, typically you would animate an empty object instead.

---

If you *really* want you could use a Python script (or PyDriver) to modify the cursor location from reading FCurve values. So it is possible, just not convenient.